# i tried to deploy nodejs application on iis it shows error

Tags: node.js, iis

iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.

HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP subStatus: 1002
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is 'true'.

In addition to the log of stdout and stderr of the node.exe process, consider using debugging and ETW traces to further diagnose the problem.

The last 64k of the output generated by the node.exe process to stderr is shown below:

**Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:**

```
Error: Invalid port number: \\.\pipe\0347a3ad-a892-4089-a2f3-6e49876e9adb
    at normalizePort (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SchoolPtm-Mujeeb\server.js:16:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SchoolPtm-Mujeeb\server.js:23:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\iisnode\interceptor.js:210:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
```

Comment: did you consider changing the port number ? make sure no app is taking your current port by running this cmd as admin : Netstat -na

Answer (score 0):

Please try to [add the IIS_IUSRS full permission](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/scripts/setupsamples.bat#L41), and check if it works or not.

> 1.Go to your windows folder application ad right click on properties.
>
> 2. From the Security section, click on Edit and then click on Add.
> iisnode encountered an error when processing the request
>
> 3.Now, from the Advanced, use the Find Now and then select the IIS_IUSRS option.
>
> 4.Then, Allow the following option: Full control
>
> 5.Finally, Restart the application on IIS

If it still not works, please try to execute below command.

```
npm cache clear  --force
```

Answer (score 0):

the error was outbound rule was not not added to the port in which my node app was  deployed ,by default node app on iis block post requests ....

and also we should do all the required things to deploy nodejs app on iis

1. download iisnode
2. download urlRewrite
3. give the all required permissions to iis so so your app will run          ,you can do that by right click on your application folder click on properties > Security give all permissions to IIS_IUSRS .

4.configure your web.config :

```
     <configuration> 
    <system.webServer>
  
     <handlers>
       <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*"  modules="iisnode" />
     </handlers>
  
     <rewrite>
       <rules>
         <rule name="nodejs">
           <match url="(.*)" />
           <conditions>
             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
           </conditions>
           <action type="Rewrite" url="/app.js" />
         </rule>
       </rules>
     </rewrite>
  
     <security>
       <requestFiltering>
         <hiddenSegments>
           <add segment="node_modules" />
           <add segment="iisnode" />
         </hiddenSegments>
       </requestFiltering>
     </security>
     </system.webServer> 
 </configuration>
```

your app will run properly..